# Flash / Flex compiler for Android

Tags: android, flash, apache-flex, mobile, flash-builder

Has anyone heard anything about an Android app which will compile Flash and/or Flex projects into a SWF or other outputs (eg., for mobile) directly on the Android device itself? I'm looking for something like a basic version of Flash Builder on an Android tablet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You MIGHT be able to build one using the flex SDK tools that are written in Java, but a prepackaged app that will do that for you really doesn't exist. You're probably better served running a webservice that does the compilation: it will be MUCH faster than trying to do a customized version of the flex compiler that performs adequately on an Android tablet.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely have to look into using a web-service compiler.